# TS Cant make union type with inferred values

Tags: typescript, redux, parameters, union-types

I am attempting to streamline the types of a shared reducer in React, it currently works but I want to make the shared action dispatcher function to know the types that can be passed onto it based on the type of the action.

You can see a simple example of the code here; (and what I tried)
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKZQCIEMAmWAUUqyUAXImCALYBGqATgJTkBucMOiA3gL4DcAKFCRYCRLhzY8%20ZojYdu-IeGjwkaKABksAGwJZ6Ac3Jc9e8pVoMANIg4XqderZL1yrmGEM9Z8zr0EBTyJ6YCwIVEQAZXQpLABBI24BRFTEKABPAAdUcgAiKIBRABUAfQx4irzrFLSDY0QABQMsKnQGZAAeTJy4YBRY3CwAPgBtAAYAXUEeASCwELCIxHicSSHEw2S09OzcxDzKjHLK%20Ora1PryZvpW9vountQ%208TW44Zm54IYlyJitLDabZpJ75IplTTxSHnHZXJotNohR57F4abR6MZTT4CJ4rVQIZCbRAAXmigzwRIAPis3hsktT-tptIJUAAPLJwehQXY5PGiMDIEl8tSEoyjPJPPLTOYQAnc8L85DkABKqFl9BwnXi%20IFtiwYAywyFXAu0RKJwq7nJWBqOyOFvi5AkcVtaXBpUhkKtAL0NSUyhEakQOBgyCyWCgEAAFvg4drFZtGMDLjrkKN6gA6J6TWNGDP1RjYgD0RcQxT2wbgxAWiCoEejthoIG5yCjcBAOk4yBAhkMxG5bXScEQIDQiAA5JYnOO7AKiLhEC9xx4vOOBCGw-WY1xQQd3RUqnqjPksMgcHkfEA)

```
function setDada(test: number): void {};
function addDada(): void {};
function setLala(arg: {lala: number, id: number, str: string}): void {};

interface SetDadaArg {
    type: "SET_DADA",
    arg: Parameters<typeof setDada>[0];
}

interface AddDadaArg {
    type: "ADD_DADA",
    arg: Parameters<typeof addDada>;
}

interface SetLaLa {
    type: "SET_LALA",
    arg: Parameters<typeof setLala>[0];
}

type ActionsArg = SetDadaArg | AddDadaArg | SetLaLa;
export type Actions = ActionsArg["type"];

const actions: Record<Actions, any> = {
    SET_DADA: setDada,
    ADD_DADA: addDada,
    SET_LALA: setLala,
};

function dispatch(arg: ActionsArg) {
    actions[arg.type](arg.arg);
}

// Type doesnt match, but should suggest me to use 'number' instead of 'string'
dispatch({type: "SET_DADA", arg: "asd"})
```

The idea is to define the functions once (in the reducer, but on top of the example for simplicity) and then pass the types of the arguments to the action dispatcher function as `{type, arg}`.

I can remove `Parameters<>` from the interfaces and assign the expected values there, and it would work (suggestions on the dispatcher show as defined in the interface), but doing that would require me to type the function argument again, and so could cause problems if both are typed differently. Is this a limitation on TypeScript or maybe theres a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
function setDada(test: number): void { };
function addDada(): void { };
function setLala(arg: { lala: number, id: number, str: string }): void { };

const actions = {
    SET_DADA: setDada,
    ADD_DADA: addDada,
    SET_LALA: setLala,
};
export type Actions = keyof typeof actions;

type DispatchParameter<K extends Actions> = {
    type: K,
    arg: Parameters<typeof actions[K]>[0]
};
function dispatch<K extends Actions>(arg: DispatchParameter<K>) {
    actions[arg.type](arg.arg as any);
}

// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
dispatch({ type: "SET_DADA", arg: "abc"});
// OK
dispatch({ type: "SET_DADA", arg: 1});
```

In addition to be much terser, this has maintainability and refactoring advantages. All all of types track via type inference. All one must do to add a new or remove an action is to add or remove a property from the `actions` object.

The key to this approach is allowing type inference to do its job. Rather than specifying 
imprecise intermediate types, such as `Record<Actions, any>`.